# Laravel-8 Livewire-2 was hacked when passing data through wire:click

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

When I passing data in the blade file through **wire:click="data('text')"** then it's working fine.


But if I change the value in the blade file like **wire:click="data('new text')"**, then this value changed.

This is my blade file

```
<button wire:click="delete('1')" type="button">Delete Record</button>
```

But when I change the value in the blade file and click on the button then this value changed.

```
<button wire:click="delete('10')" type="button">Delete Record</button>
```

Please! tell me. How this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, that's how ***any and all*** forms work - be it Livewire, a standard HTTP form or via Ajax. This can be done with any data the user passes to your server, and it's normal, expected behaviour. There is no way you can prevent it entirely. Users can manipulate any of the data they send themselves.

The lesson here is *don't trust user input!* And to act on that, you need authorisation and validation of all incoming requests. This must be done on the server where you accept the request (meaning in PHP) and not in the client (like JavaScript), as anything client-side can be manipulated by the user like you've just seen.

Laravel offers policies and guards, so that you very easily can validate that the user has access to perform given actions and change or delete the record they attempt to act on. This makes validation and authorisation very easy in Laravel projects, but there's no magic - you have to implement it for all of the requests where users can pass data or call actions in your application.